# Instagram oEmbed - URL signature mismatch for thumbnail_url

Tags: instagram, oembed

Is there any way how to correctly fetch the thumbnail image for video from Instagram oEmbed?

The typical `thumbnail_url` in oEmbed response now is `https://scontent-cdg2-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/5c0c62bb1aec72c31a9e72680b9d839b/5C37201B/t51.2885-15/sh0.08/e35/p640x640/47693743_354556005338968_7959923928510913600_n.jpg` that produces "URL signature mismatch" instead of the image.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do, is to use the shortlink provided by instagram, you can find this or either via the embed function in the UI or via the API, In the API shows as 'link', then add '/media' at the end, this will redirect to the resource without need to sign the calls.

Hope helps